# How to create an Oracle trigger that updates another table?

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

Imagine two tables:

TableA with order headers and
TableB with order items

Uniqe link between the tables = ID

I need (I think) two triggers:
When a (date) field TableA.Q is updated, all (date) field(s) on TableB.Q should be updated with the same value as TableA.Q where TableA.ID = TableB.ID.
When a record of TableB is inserted or updated, field TableB.Q should be updated with TableA.Q where TableA.ID = TableB.ID

How to do this?
Oracle version we use is 11gR2.

Comment: Sounds to me as if your db design is not ok. There should be no need for this kind of update. Just select greatest(TableA.Q,TableB.Q) and you will be fine. Consider even dropping field TableB.Q and receive the information completely via join.

Comment: I agree with @Radagast81. However if you want to go with the approach. Looks like you need 3 Triggers. 1) Insert Trigger on TableB to insert on table A 2) Update Trigger on tableB to update table A 3)  Update Trigger on table A to update table B

Comment: Why do you think there is any benefit in duplicating the A.Q value in every related row in B? All it gives you is a need to extra storage (a tiny amount, but sill) and a maintenance headache. If you ever need the equivalent of the B.Q value just join A and B together and use A.Q.

Comment: Apart from bad design and storage issue as mentioned by experts, You will also get a mutating triggers issue(error something like mentioned at the end) and you will have to code more to get out of it. 


Error: **ORA-04091: table <<tab;e name>> is mutating, trigger/function may not see it**

Comment: The approach won't work. Lets say if you update date in ORDER_DETAILS then the  update trigger on ORDER DETAIL  will update the ORDER HEADER. However as the HEADER also has a trigger to update DETAIL it'll try to update the DETAILS. Which results in a cycle. Better approach is to use date in only detail. and not so good approach is to add only one way trigger